# How to support CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos

i'm just new with linux and basically what i need to do is that I have an installer (an application) that supports CentOS 6.0-6.1. I really don't know what to do . my boss asked me to install this installer to CentOS 6.3 and it appears always platform is not supported etc etc. Our installer is depended on kernel it reads the current kernel used when boot. So what I did I downloaded a kernel that corresponds to the CentOS 6.1 where my plan is i'll just pick this new downloaded kernel if i boot the server once again and try to install the installer... but I can't find the grub.conf and I'm using cli I dont have GUI where I can pick options where to boot. please help and if you have any suggestions that would be great. thanks!

Comment: The actual errors given when you try to run your installer would help.

Comment: i understand, just that my boss wants me to experiment etc. i can't help myself. but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please read our FAQ. Among other things it says you should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.** To make your question practical and answerable, you really need to describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just download kernel, you have to install it.
You can install older kernel on CentOS 6.3 like as follows:

```
rpm -ivh --oldpackage http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-debug-2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

It will be automatically set as default boot kernel. You can also change default kernel in  `/boot/grub/grub.conf`

Comment: thank you evolver for the quick response. im doing it right now and still retrieving. by the way that's my problem i have a hard time looking for my grub.conf. i only have /boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz but no grub.conf.

Comment: Also look into /boot/grub/menu.lst